# Actualizar un campo cuando depende de otro

Tags: php, mysql

Hola excelente madrugada, estoy realizando la actualización de una tabla y me encuentro con un inconveniente

Tengo una tabla llamada orden4 que contiene:

```
    ID   Nombre    No_Orden    Tipo_Orden    Fecha   
________________________________________________________  
    123   Juan     AGH-09-00      S01      2019/01/29

    123   Juan     AQE-01-23      S03      2019/02/05

    123   Juan     ERD-07-87      S09      2019/03/10
________________________________________________________
```

y una tabla llamada general con:

```
    ID   Nombre  No_Orden    
__________________________________ 
    123   Juan               
__________________________________
```

Actualizo con la siguiente consulta pero me genera error

```
$actualizar = "UPDATE orden4 AS o4 INNER JOIN general AS g ON o4.ID = g.ID SET o4.No_Orden = g.No_orden WHERE (select max(o4.Fecha))"
```

Resultado esperado:

```
   ID----Nombre----No_Orden  
__________________________________
   123----Juan-----ERD-07-87  
__________________________________
```

Necesito que actualice el `No_Orden` con la Fecha más reciente de la tabla orden4

Sus consejos me serían de gran ayuda

Comment: Quieres tomar el "No_orden" de una tabla para añadirselo a la otra tabla?

Comment: Así es Patrick, tengo varios registros que se repiten en la tabla orden4 con el mismo ID, y van cambiando los No_Orden, Tipo_Orden y Fecha. Requiero que mi resultado final,  tener el ID del Usuario,  Nombre y No_orden (con la fecha más reciente)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

De este modo debería funcionar:

```
UPDATE general g
    SET g.No_Orden = (
        SELECT No_Orden
        FROM orden
        WHERE g.ID=ID
        ORDER BY Fecha DESC LIMIT 1
    );
```

Dado que la columna que interesa obtener es `No_Orden`, puedes indicar en la sub-consulta que quieres precisamente esa columna, haciendo coincidir en cada resultado el valor `ID` de las dos tablas, pero ordenando los registros por `Fecha` de forma descendente y limitando a `1`. Esta consulta actualizará todas las filas de la tabla `general` con el dato que le corresponde.

Comment: A. Cedano puedo preguntar un par de dudas

Comment: Porqué tienes dos cláusulas WHERE

Comment: @user11149721 para filtrar por el `ID=123` en ambas tablas. Esto sería lo mismo que si en `JOIN` hicieras `ON g.ID=o.ID WHERE g.ID=123`. Dado que es un `UPDATE` aquí obtenemos de forma definitiva en la sub-consulta el dato que queremos y en la parte de afuera del `UPDATE` seteamos ese dato a la fila indicada por el `WHERE`

Comment: Muchas Gracias A. Cedano, he probado la consulta con un registro en especifíco y me ha funcionado de maravilla.                                                :3 Gracias

Comment: pero cuando intento pasarla de forma general (para que realice la misma consulta para toda la tabla,  ya que no es el único caso que se presenta, la consulta me lanza un error)

Comment: UPDATE general AS g,
    (SELECT No_Orden FROM orden4 WHERE ID=ID ORDER BY Fecha DESC LIMIT 1) o
SET 
    g.No_Orden=o.No_Orden 
WHERE g.ID=o.ID;

Comment: #1054 - La columna 'o.ID' en where clause es desconocida,    este es el error que me lanza phpMyAdmin

Comment: @user11149721 prueba así: `UPDATE general AS g, (SELECT No_Orden FROM orden4  ORDER BY Fecha DESC LIMIT 1) o SET g.No_Orden=o.No_Orden WHERE g.ID=o.ID;`  pero haz primero una copia de la base de datos si está en producción, no sea que te fastidie todo. Esa consulta actualizará todas las filas donde `g.ID=o.ID`

Comment: OK le hago la copia ahora mismo.

Comment: he pasado la consulta y me arroja:                                          #1054 - La columna 'o.ID' en where clause es desconocida

Comment: UPDATE entregable AS e, (SELECT noor3 FROM 4fidis_03 ORDER BY fecha03 DESC LIMIT 1) 4f SET e.noor3=4f.noor3 WHERE e.rpu= rpu;

Comment: Voy a hacer una prueba con datos reales, dame un momento...

Comment: omití en la cláusula WHERE o.ID y lo pase solo ID, y me busco el No_Orden más reciente de toda la tabla orden4 y lo inserto en todos los registros, menos mal tengo la copia.

Comment: Por eso te dije que hagas copia, siempre que se vaya a modificar datos masivos hay que hacerlo porque cualquier descuido y zasss, se va todo al garete. Revisa la consulta ahora en mi respuesta. La he probado sobre datos reales y funciona perfectamente.

Comment: Si hice la copia. reviso la respuesta

Comment: He probado la consulta y funciona perfecto, A. Cedano le agradezco mucho el tiempo que se tomó en ayudarme, ya había tardado bastante en esto. Muchas Gracias y que tenga una excelente tarde